# HTTPClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request using Spring REST template

Tags: java, android, spring, gson

```
String Stringifiedjson = new Gson().toJson(user);
Log.d("SpringAndroid", Stringifiedjson);

HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(new 
         MediaType("application", "json")));

HttpEntity <? > requestEntity = new HttpEntity < Object >   
       (Stringifiedjson, requestHeaders);

GsonHttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
List < HttpMessageConverter <? >> messageConverters = 
      new ArrayList < HttpMessageConverter <? >> ();
messageConverters.add(messageConverter);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

try {   
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.
         exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);               
}
```

I am getting a 400 Bad Request, but when i send the `Stringifiedjson` in my fiddler. I get a valid `response`. Now how to post the GSON Object using RestTemplate

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. I solved it by passing the Object itself instead of a String containing the JSON representation of that Object.

In short, I changed:

```
String jsonObject = convertToJSON(myObject);
HttpEntity <? > requestEntity = new HttpEntity <String>   
       (jsonObject, requestHeaders);
```

To:

```
HttpEntity <? > requestEntity = new HttpEntity <MyObject>   
       (myObject, requestHeaders);
```

MyObject in this case is the java bean I want to be catched in the @RequestBody parameter of the Controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be with your http request headers
The below worked for me.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```